# Can flutter extend colors?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm tired of having to build a separate class to store color values. I hope to extend Colors and use Colors.aaa directly.

I wrote the following code：

```
extension colorExt on Colors {
  static const Color cementTwo = const Color(0xff999990);
  static Color aaa = Color(0xDD000000);
 
}
```

But it does not work.
Can someone tell me why and how to correctly implement my needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this,

```
extension colorExt on Color {
    Color get newColor => Color(0xDD000000);
}
   
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    Color color;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        color: color.newColor,
        width: 50,
        height: 50
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this method is actually no advantage compared to creating a new class to put some colors specifically, I hope it can extend static methods

Comment: Yes you are right about it, but probably not possible with extensions because they work on objects in general.